Failed to display array in KnockoutJS in html page magento2.4
I tried to add multiple custom fees in checkout page, i tried to fetch labels of fees as array and need to show on by one, but its fail in KnockoutJS binding, below is my fee.html and fee.js file code
fee.js::
function (ko, Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
    'use strict';
     var feeLabels = window.checkoutConfig.fee_labels || [];
     var custom_fee_amount = window.checkoutConfig.custom_fee_amount;

    return Component.extend({
        feeLabels: ko.observableArray(feeLabels),
        getFormattedPrice: ko.observable(priceUtils.formatPrice(custom_fee_amount, quote.getPriceFormat())),
    ...
    })

And my fee.html:
<!-- ko foreach: feeLabels -->
        <tr class="totals fee excl">
            <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: $data + ' ' + $parent.getExFeeLabel()"></th>
              <td class="amount">
                 <span class="price" data-bind="text: $parent.getFormattedPrice()"></span>
              </td>
       </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->

